# storing arraylist from existing arraylist in android

Tags: java, android, for-loop, arraylist

Below is the List Class.

```
public class Abc {

    String pincode, state, name, phNo;

    public Abc(String pincode, String state, String name, String phNo) {
        this.pincode = pincode;
        this.state = state;
        this.name = name;
        this.phNo = phNo;
    }

    public String getPincode() {
        return pincode;
    }

    public void setPincode(String pincode) {
        this.pincode = pincode;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPhNo() {
        return phNo;
    }

    public void setPhNo(String phNo) {
        this.phNo = phNo;
    }
}
```

I am adding the data to the list.

```
    List<Abc> abcs = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Abc> customList = new ArrayList<>();
    abcs.add(new Abc("600025", "Delhi", "gambhir", "565632552"));
    abcs.add(new Abc("600026", "Punjab", "yuvi", "565632553"));
    abcs.add(new Abc("600027", "Punjab", "bhajji", "565632554"));
    abcs.add(new Abc("600028", "Delhi", "kohli", "565632555"));
    abcs.add(new Abc("600029", "Karnataka", "dravid", "565632556"));
    abcs.add(new Abc("600030", "Delhi", "rohit", "565632557"));
    abcs.add(new Abc("600031", "Kerla", "sreeshanth", "565632558"));
```

I need a separate list who lives in Delhi how to achieve this logic.
I tried like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < abcs.size(); i++) {
      if(abcs.get(i).getName().equals("Delhi")){
            customList.addAll(i,abcs);
      }
    }
```

But in my customList no data is added. Can anyone help me.

Comment: try putting the Abc class object in your customList.

**customList.add(abcs.get(i));**

Comment: wait.. I will check..

Comment: This condition `if(abcs.get(i).getName().equals("Delhi")){` should be `if(abcs.get(i).getState().equals("Delhi")){`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This condition

```
if(abcs.get(i).getName().equals("Delhi")){
```

should be

```
if(abcs.get(i).getState().equals("Delhi")){
```

because you'r storing state name in second parameter and in `"name"` variable there is not value for `"Delhi"`

Answer (score 3):

Again change code to

```
for (int i = 0; i < abcs.size(); i++) {
        if (abcs.get(i).getState().equals("Delhi")) {
            customList.add(abcs.get(i));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can create a custom model for storing info about only delhi users.

```
public class CustomList{
private ArrayList<Abc> abc;
public CustomList(ArrayList<Abc> abc){
this.abc = abc;
}
public void setAbc(ArrayList<Abc> abc){
this.abc = abc;
}

public ArrayList<Abc> getAbc(){
return abc;
}
}
```

Now, you can add your code and check for Delhi users:

```
ArrayLis<CustomList> customList = new ArrayList<CustomList>();
for (int i = 0; i < abcs.size(); i++) {
      if(abcs.get(i).getState().equals("Delhi")){
            customList.add(new CustomList(abcs));
      }
    }
```

retrieve by: `customList.get(position).getAbc();`